# calcul of sum from variable location cell

Tags: vb.net, excel

I want to calculate `SUM` this is my code:

```
 Dim lastrow As Integer 
 Dim lastcol As Integer, thiscol As Integer = CInt(j) 
 xlWorkSheet = CType(xlWorkBook.Sheets(ComboBox1.Text),Excel.Worksheet) 
 xlWorkSheet.Activate()
 xlApp.Visible = True 
 With xlWorkSheet 
    xlWorkSheet.Select() 
    j = (xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Row + 1 & vbCrLf&xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Column) 
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlUp).Row 
    lastcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.xlToLeft).Column 
    For thiscol = j To lastcol 
        .Cells(lastrow + 1, thiscol).Value = _ 
        xlApp.Sum(.Range(.Cells(1, thiscol), .Cells(lastrow, thiscol))) 
    Next 
 End With
```

I want to use the variable 'j' as integer not string.

Comment: Looking at this line I don't understand what you are trying to do. This will never give you an Integer: j = (xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Row + 1 &                      vbCrLf&xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Column)

Comment: Strip off the part: & vbCrLf&xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Column

Comment: xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Column i want this to know the first cell
then i want to calcul the sum

Comment: Then use: j = xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Column

Comment: j=xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Row + 1 & vbCrLf&xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Column 
i want all of this to know the first cell in the table then i calculate the sum using this code:
 For thiscol As Integer = j To lastcol
                .Cells(lastrow + 1, thiscol).Value = _
                    xlApp.Sum(.Range(.Cells(1, thiscol), .Cells(lastrow, thiscol)))
            Next

Comment: I think you have to use 2 variables firstRow = xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Row + 1 and firstColumn = xlApp.Cells.SpecialCells(2).Column.